# Implementing a shift-click with a sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm writing a small proof-of-concept app for something I'd like to add to my web application. I found some previous code here and made alterations to accommodate my needs.I have a sortable element, that currently uses ctrl-click and regular click events to move items around. After extended googling, and searching - I'm posting a question, hoping someone has some good advice for me. Please be advised, I'm still relatively new to coding.

I'd like to implement a shift-click to function much like windows' does. When the user shift clicks one of the items in the sortable that item should be selected, and upon clicking the second item (if relevant) then select all the items between it so that they can all be moved.

http://jsfiddle.net/pYaRv/1/

Code:

```
clicked_list = []

$("ul").on('click', 'li', function (e) {
if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    temp2 = $(this)

    if (jQuery.inArray(temp2[0]["innerText"], clicked_list) == -1){
        clicked_list.push(temp2[0]["innerText"])
    }else{
        index = jQuery.inArray(temp2[0]["innerText"], clicked_list)
        clicked_list.splice(index, 1)
    }

    $("#information").text("Ctrl-Clicked " + (temp2[0]["innerText"]))
}
else if(e.shiftKey)
{
    temp3 = $(this)
    $("#information").text("Shift-Clicked " + (temp3[0]["innerText"]))        
} 

else 
{
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected'))
    {
        $("#information").text("Un-Clicked " + (temp[0]["innerText"]))
        $(this).removeClass('selected')
    }
    else{
        temp = $(this)
        $("#information").text("Clicked " + (temp[0]["innerText"]))
        $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass('selected');                    
    }


}
}).sortable({
connectWith: "ul",
delay: 150,
revert: 0,
helper: function (e, item) {
    if (!item.hasClass('selected')) {
        item.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    }   

    var elements = item.parent().children('.selected').clone();

    $("#information").text("Moved " + elements.length + " item(s)")

    item.data('multidrag', elements).siblings('.selected').remove();


    var helper = $('<li/>');
    return helper.append(elements);
},
stop: function (e, ui) {
    var elements = ui.item.data('multidrag');


    ui.item.after(elements).remove();
}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my research this weekend, I came across the following JQuery plugin that does exactly what I need it to do.

https://github.com/shvetsgroup/jquery.multisortable